# Конвертация gif в mp4 | webm

Tags: php, ffmpeg, lib, gif, .webm

Существуют ли какие-то библиотеки для конвертации "на лету" получаемых *gif* файлов? Или может какие-то уже готовые решения.

Чтобы можно было подключить их в проект и с их помощью получать на выходе видеофайлы из gif-анимации?

Comment: GOogle: Пробуй https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg или здесь что-нибудь посмотри https://github.com/search?l=PHP&q=gif+to+video&type=Code

Comment: Укажите, что Вы уже пробовали, и почему те решения Вам не подошли. Иначе высока вероятность, что вопрос закроют и/или Вам будут отвечать первыми ссылками из Google. [**Например**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27396842/5951529). Спасибо.